# Slick.Grid is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, slickgrid

I am using slickgrid on Symfony4

Symfony4 uses `webpack` system.

So my source code is like this ,

but it shows the error

`Slick.Grid is not a constructor`

Normally this error means it doesn't load the variable, however I can't figure out where is wrong.

in app.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
require('slickgrid');

console.log(Slick); // it shows in console `{Event: ƒ, EventData: ƒ, EventHandler: ƒ, Range: ƒ, NonDataRow: ƒ, …}`


$(document).ready(function() {

    var grid;
    var columns = [
      {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title"},
      {id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration"},
      {id: "%", name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete"},
      {id: "start", name: "Start", field: "start"},
      {id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish"},
      {id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven"}
    ];

    var options = {
      enableCellNavigation: true,
      enableColumnReorder: false
    };

      var data = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        data[i] = {
          title: "Task " + i,
          duration: "5 days",
          percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
          start: "01/01/2009",
          finish: "01/05/2009",
          effortDriven: (i % 5 == 0)
        };
      }
      grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slickgrid is a poorly written library, with bad behavior like relying on global variables, relying on the window object, and having side effects simply by loading the library.

**Option 1**

To use dangerously designed libraries like this in modern projects, you need to use modern forks of them. Use [slickgrid-es6](https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/slickgrid-es6) instead.

**Option 2**

If you want to keep using the non-modern version in npm, it looks like you need to do:

```
require('slickgrid/slick.core.js')
require('slickgrid/slick.grid.js')
```

And then you'll have access to the global `Slick` and `Slick.Core`. This isn't recommended because the library follows bad practices, and despite being published to npm, doesn't follow any npm standards. It's especially scary this isn't documented at all in the npm package. It being update to date isn't related to this problem.

**Option 3**

Or if you prefer not to use build tools, you could simply include the SlickGrid script tag and use the global variable `Slick` and `Slick.Grid`.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I use slickgrid installed by npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/slickgrid this slickgrid looks well maintainanced.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andy Ray!!! This explanation really helps to understand the situation. I didn't think slickgrid from npm was obsolete. I will try `slickgrid-es6` or option3.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of the 6pac repo. I predominantly use ASP .NET which has its own bundling system, and have never touched NPM. The 6pac fork is just maintaining the original repo. NPM support was added by request, just as a delivery system rather than a packaging system. Various people have fiddled with the packaging, but I have not had any luck finding anyone who really knows their way around that. If you'd like to write a warning, I'm happy to post it. One day, I'll have time to research NPM and perhaps introduce that to my projects.

Comment: I'm perfectly happy to migrate to the ES6 repo ongoing (frankly, I don't have time to maintain the project properly), it's just a matter of evaluating its stability and feature set, and working out how to use the NPM export/import system.

Comment: I believe the comment in Option 2 `doesn't follow any npm standards` is **wrong**, NPM is just a package manager, it's only used to download packages. Instead what should be written is that SlickGrid is not written in ES6 and the reason is simple, the library is over 10 years old and ES6 did not exist at that time. So I suggest that the person do real research instead of bashing on an Open Source project that has 10k votes. Also note that I'm a contributor to that lib, and it's a little frustrating to see such incorrect answer being posted, please update your answer with correct information

Comment: Being written in ES3 isn't related to it being a poor npm actor

Comment: I will stay with my previous post, NPM is a package manager, and it has nothing to do with a lib being written in ES3 or ES6. Pulling a package (which simply download the code to the `node_modules` folder) has nothing to do with how you use (or import) the lib in your project. What you are referring to, are modules, again this has nothing to do with NPM being a package manager. I understand that you want to mention that it's hard to use the lib in the new ES6 and modules world, and I understand that, but that is another subject unrelated to NPM itself.

Comment: @Andy Ray Yes, slickgrid-es6 looks more relevant, so I tried it yesterday using info from [link] (https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/slickgrid-es6). But I didn't find the location of **grid-config** file which is required as stated in the statement : `import { options, columns } from './grid-config';` in the example. Where is it ?

Comment: @Ben McIntyre Do you also contribute in http://slickgrid.net ? In that page, the writer mentions ag-Grid which I am currently using (community edition) for my project. Unfortunately some features such as grouping are only available in paid edition. So I am searching for other lib for that purpose. Then I remembered slickgrid, found it meet my need. My app uses React 16.7, so I need to integrate slickgrid in React. I did quick research on it yesterday, but only found 1 lib, i.e React-Slickgrid, but it is based on old lib. So I will probably use slickgrid-es6 and wrap it myself in React.

Comment: I find that slickgrid-es6 is the only available lib for modern (ES6) version. React-slickgrid looks to be based on old lib, so I won't use it for my React app. I hope slickgrid community will contribute to the advancement of slickgrid, because among other **fully free** grid libraries, it is the only one that meets my need. Editable, grouping is my requirement. I also hope Michael Leibman would eventually contribute again. :)

Comment: Yes I put slickgrid.net together. I don't think MLeibman is coming back :--(  but if he did, he would jump to a modern branch (probably 6pac). Re slickgrid-es6, it looks old, see my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293466/adding-function-to-namespace-module-from-another-file?noredirect=1#comment97369944_53293466