# Adding function to namespace/module from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I ma writing custom editor for slickgrid.

slick.editors.js

```
/***
 * Contains basic SlickGrid editors.
 * @module Editors
 * @namespace Slick
 */

(function ($) {
  // register namespace
  $.extend(true, window, {
    "Slick": {
      "Editors": {
        "Text": TextEditor,
        "Integer": IntegerEditor,
        "Float": FloatEditor,
        "Date": DateEditor,
        "YesNoSelect": YesNoSelectEditor,
        "Checkbox": CheckboxEditor,
        "PercentComplete": PercentCompleteEditor,
        "LongText": LongTextEditor
      }
    }
  });

  function TextEditor(args) {
    var $input;
    var defaultValue;
    var scope = this;
.
.
.
})(jQuery);
```

The function can be called under namespace 
`import { Editors } from 'slickgrid-es6';`
`Editors.TextEditor()`

Now I want to add here myTextEditor(args) function, but not altering slick.editors.js file.

in myText.js the function is written like this below

```
var myTextEditor = function MyTextEditor(args) {
  var $input;
  var defaultValue;
  var scope = this;
```

then I want to add this under Slick namespace in Editors module.
so that I can call `Editors.myTextEditor()`

Is it possible??

Comment: worth letting us know the slickgrid repo you are using. that editor file looks like the vanilla repo, but you seem to be using the es6 version too

Comment: note also that you can just declare your custom editor locally in the page or file and reference the local editor object as the 'editor' property of a column - the editor doesn't *need* to live in the slick-editors.js file

Comment: My repo is slickgrid-es6 I dont use vanilla version.

Comment: Thanks to your pointing out. I found out , I copy the source from wrong repo. It made me confusing. My problem is solved .

Comment: I tried slickgrid-es6 yesterday but didn't find the location of the grid-config file as declared in the statement `import { options, columns } from './grid-config';` in the example. Where did you find the location of the file ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ben McIntyre Have you tried the library ? What is your opinion ? Since you are the current maintainer of  6pack repo, I can trust your opinion. slickgrid-es6 seems to be the only modern (ES6) version of slickgrid, so we should give it a try.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the 6pac Slickgrid repo is the only one that is being consistently maintained. It appears that slickgrid-es6 was forked from the MLeibman repo several years ago (although it wan't officially forked using GIT, the initial version was just committed) and has none of the features or updates from the 6pac repo. So it is very likely to have problems with jQuery 3.x and other age-related issues. If it was me, I'd work out a diff of the final version of the slickgrid-es6 to the initial commit, and try to apply that to the current 6pac version.

Comment: Note that @ghiscoding (GitHub) also maintains and aurelia and angular repos, but these are dependent on the 6pac fork.